# Ist der Dandy immer auch ein Lebemann?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrase, usage

> ...ist ein Dandy und Lebemann (und umgekehrt)

ist eine [recht häufig verwendete Phrase](http://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&q=%22dandy%20und%20lebemann%22%20%7C%20%22lebemann%20und%20dandy%22&oq=%22dandy%20und%20lebemann%22%20%7C%20%22lebemann%20und%20dandy%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=107336l113696l0l114162l29l16l0l1l0l0l268l268l2-1l1l0)

Mehrere zusammengehörige Fragen stellen sich mir dazu:

- Ist *Dandy* und *Lebemann* nicht ziemlich dasselbe (eng. - ger., das Negativum zum Dandy wär wohl der Playboy, als neg. konnotiert seh ich Dandy nicht)
- wenn, aber auch wenn nicht, ist es doch ziemlich redundant bzw. warum wird es dann trotzdem so oft zusammen verwendet (Hendiadyoin ?)
- ergo ist diese Phrase evtl. eine feststehende und was ist der etymologische Ursprung?
- *Dandy und Lebemann* ist wesentlich häufiger als umgekehrt (deutet imho auch auf feststehende Phrase hin)
- ich überinterpretier das alles, da man Sprache genauer beobachtet wenn man hier regelmässig liesst und immer nur Bäume aber nicht den Wald sieht :P

Mal sehen ob ein paar Dandy's und Lebemänner/-frauen sich hier outen.

PS: wie nennt man weiblichen Dandy? ... Mandy?

Comment: Es gibt auch einen Kleidungsstil *Dandy* als Bruderstil des Lolita-Stils (siehe [Dunkelsuess.de](http://dunkelsuess.de) ). Dieser wird allerdings oft auch von Frauen getragen, die ihn trotzdem *Dandy* nennen. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Ich denke, dass *Dandy* und *Lebemann* eine ähnliche, aber nicht exakt gleiche, Bedeutung haben.

**Dandy** beschreibt laut Duden einen *sich übertrieben modisch kleidenden Mann*. Das etymologische Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache beschreibt Dandys als *junge Leute, die in auffälliger Bekleidung Kirche oder Jahrmarkt besuchen*. Der Fokus liegt hier also in erster Linie auf der extravaganten Kleidung.

**Lebemann** beschreibt laut Duden einen *eleganten, reichen Mann, der im Luxus lebt und dem sinnlichen Genuss ergeben ist*. Das Wort *Lebemann* lenkt die Aufmerksamkeit also auf den Lebensstil.

Viele Dandys sind natürlich auch Lebemänner, und viele Lebemänner auch Dandys, aber beides gilt vielleicht nicht immer. Ein Lebemann wird sich wohl selten in Lumpen kleiden, aber muss nicht unbedingt einen ganz herausragenden Sinn für Mode haben. Ein Dandy wird zwar meistens reich sein und sich von sinnlichen Genüssen treiben lassen, aber eine glückliche und treue Ehe macht die Bezeichnung als Dandy nicht notwendigerweise unzutreffend.

Ich persönlich würde *Dandy und Lebemann* also vor allem dann verwenden, wenn ich ausdrücklich klarstellen will, dass derjenige sich ganz besonders modisch kleidet, und außerdem einen luxuriösen, von Leidenschaft getriebenen Lebensstil hat. Ich würde *Dandy* alleine verwenden, wenn ich vor allem über das Erscheinungsbild informieren möchte, und ich würde *Lebemann* alleine verwenden, wenn das Augenmerk eher auf dem Verhalten liegt.